# Confusion on syntax for data attribute

Tags: html, syntax, custom-data-attribute

I just need to know if this is the correct way of doing this.

I am trying to create an anchor tag that has an embedded image in it using a data attr. This will be used to determine what will be displayed at different media queries.

is this syntax correct? I have no idea. I am using bootstrap as my framework

```
  <div class ="col-lg-12" data-test="<a href='http://www.army.mil/veterans/'  target='_blank'><img  id='va_badge' class ='badges img-responsive' src='images/armybadge.png' alt='Army Veteran Badge'></a>"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct. (You can check this using a validator like http://validator.w3.org) A `data-*` attribute may have any value. It may cpntain “<” characters, as they are not treated as starting a tag when inside an attribute value.

What you are going to do with the value is a completely different thing. It is all up to you. The `data-*` attributes are just containers for that that you can process with a script.